# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 CookieAuthentication sliding expiration

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity-2

As far as I can gather, both `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpirationTimeSpan` and the `SecurityStampValidator` `validationInterval` pertain to both persistent and non-persistent cookies.

For a persistent cookie, I would like for the expiration to be in the moderately far future; I understand the default is 14 days sliding, which is fine.

For non-persistent cookies, however, besides having them expire at the end of the browser session, I would also like to have a near-future sliding expiration, such as 20 minutes.

I was expecting this to be more or less of a default setup, but I haven't found it to be an option at all. Am I missing something glaringly obvious here?

Comment: Check out this link. http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/

Comment: @A.P.S: Thanks, I've read this already. Can you elaborate on how that pertains to the question at hand?

Comment: If I set `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)`, the user will be logged out after one minute, regardless of whether or not the cookie was persistent. I'm looking for a way to only have non-persistent cookies expire.